# How to validate URL pattern of ER.RTR.RT12345?

Tags: java, regex, url

I am facing issue for validate the URL pattern like `ER.RTR.RT12345`,its return me true .But it is works fine for `https://www.sophos.com/cs-cz/support/knowledgebase/117316.aspx` this.

```
public static boolean validateURL(String url) {
    String urlPattern = "(@)?(href=')?(HREF=')?(HREF=\")?(href=\")?(http://)?(https://)?[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+(\\.\\w[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+)+(/[#&\\n\\-=?\\+\\%/\\.\\w]+)?";
    if (url.matches(urlPattern))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

How to resolves this issue ?

Comment: Not clear what the issue is. You have a URL `ER.RTR.RT12345` and you want the validation method to return `true` of `false` for it? What are the criteria?

Comment: i want the validation to  false  when validate the ER.RTR.RT12345

Comment: You should first define what it is that you want to do. Apparently you want `ER.RTR.RT12345` to return false. How about `some.domain` then? Or `SOME.DOMAIN`? How do you distinguish?

Comment: @eis actually our QA team rise this  issue .you are write i am not thinking about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's `URL` class automatically "validates" a URL string. The validation is according to

> The syntax of URL is defined by *RFC 2396: Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax*, amended by *RFC 2732: Format for Literal IPv6 Addresses in URLs*.

You can just use the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL-java.lang.String-):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL("ER.RTR.RT12345");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and manage `true` or `false` with the `catch` block. The above example throws the exception.

Comment: note that this will then fail for `www.google.com`, for example.

Comment: @eis Yes, because no protocol is defined.

Comment: Yes. That might or might not be what OP wants.

Comment: @eis And we will probably never know.

Comment: @eis I was wrong, we did get to know.